# Simple Gaussian Process Simulation on R

Tags: r, stochastic, stochastic-process

How to simulate a Gaussian process `X(t), t = 1, . . . , 200`, with mean value function `m(t) = 0` and
covariance function `r(h) = Cov(t, t + h) = exp(-|h|)`. I Know that this process is sometimes referred to as
the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process but how to plot the simulated process.

*Thanks in anticipation*

Comment: what have you tried so far?  I believe that a discretization of the continuous-time equation shown on the Wikipedia page should help: `X(t+1) = h*X(t) + rnorm(1)` should probably work

Comment: Do you know the formula for a process with that covariance structure?

Comment: Yes, its: r(h) = exp(-|h|)

Comment: The formula for a process with that covariance structure is r(h) = exp(-|h|)   @ Ricardo Semião e Castro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) definition an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process is defined by the following stochastic differential equation:
[image]
Where [image] is a wiener process, one of it's properties is that it has Gaussian increments i.e [image]

the aforementioned equation can be discretized in the following fashion:
[image]
Where [image]
And due to the Gaussian increments property of the Wiener process we have that [image]. That means that the values of the increments can be generated using `sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1)`

I coded the following function in R that takes the time vector, the mean of the process, the standard deviation and the value of theta.

```r
simulate <- function(t, mean=0, std=1, x0=mean, theta=1, number.of.points=length(t)){
  # calculate time differences
  dt <- diff(t)
  X <- vector("numeric", length=number.of.points)
  X[1] <- x0
  for(i in 1:(number.of.points-1)){
    X[i+1] <- X[i] + theta * (mean-X[i])*dt[i] + std * sqrt(dt[i])* rnorm(1)
  }
  data.frame(x=t, y=X)
}
simulate(t=1:200) %>%  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]
**Another implementation Using `purrr`**

```r
simulate <- function(t, mean=0, sd=1, theta=1, number.of.points=length(t)){
  stopifnot(!missing(t) | !missing(number.of.points))
  if(missing(t)){
    t <- 1:number.of.points
  } 

  unlist(purrr::accumulate2(vector("numeric", length=number.of.points-1), diff(t), function(x, o, y) {
    x + theta*(mean - x)* y + sqrt(y)*rnorm(1)
  }, .init=x0), use.names=F) -> X
  
  data.frame(x=t, y=X)
}
simulate(number.of.points=200) %>%  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. @Abdessabour Mtk, there is a slight different approach I have to manage here as that how to do it from basic building blocks like by computing the mean and covariance matrix of X = (X1, X2 . . . X200) and then drawing a random vector from a multivariate normal distribution using the function "rmnorm"? how to do in that way? do you have any procedure for it?

Comment: @Ticktock it might be interesting to take a look at this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/37212/50677) also i think you'll need to run multiple simulations to be able to calculate the means and covariance matrix, if you use the answer tagged using `rowMeans(sims)` will give you the means and `cov(t(sims))` will give you the covariance matrix

Comment: @ Abdessabour Mtk I am still not able to produce the results from the basic building blocks, can you please help while computing the mean and covariance matrix of X = (X1, X2 . . . X200) and then drawing a random vector from a multivariate normal distribution using the function "rmnorm"? also the covarinace function is  ```r(h)=exp(-|h|)```.  Many thanks in anticipation, Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Using the function from here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/r-code-for-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process

```
ornstein_uhlenbeck <- function(T,n,nu,lambda,sigma,x0){
  dw  <- rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(T/n))
  dt  <- T/n
  x <- c(x0)
  for (i in 2:(n+1)) {
    x[i]  <-  x[i-1] + lambda*(nu-x[i-1])*dt + sigma*dw[i-1]
  }
  return(x);
}

test <- ornstein_uhlenbeck(200, 200, 0, 0.8, 1, 0)
plot(x = seq_along(test), y = test, type = 'l')
```

(Note that it gives you only an approximate distribution as noted in one of the answers to the question in the link.)

I assumed T = 200, n = 200, nu = 0 (as you mentioned), mean reversion parameter of 0.8, sigma of 1 and the process starts at 0.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. @tester, there is a slight different approach I have to manage here as that how to do it from basic building blocks like by computing the mean and covarince matrix of X = (X1, X2 . . . X200) and then drawing
a random vector from a multivariate normal distribution using the function "rmnorm"?